# Frequent crashing and unresponsive OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

About six months ago, my MacBookPro's (summer '09) HDD died. A solid, irrecoverable failure - flashing folder question mark, utterly invisible to Disk Utility, Disk Warrior, being housed in an external housing from different machines, the Genius Bar wonder disc (you knew they have one, right?), everything.

So after testing my backup strategy to its limits, I bought a new drive ([Seagate Momentus XT 500Gb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003V6AIWU)). This drive is updated with the latest firmware [SD25](http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=215451) and I'm generally happy, the hybrid drive is everything you'd expect: nippy and reasonably huge. On a good day, my cold boot from off to active is less than a minute (much less).

But. And it's a huge but (and I have to assume it is something related to the drive):

It is crashing on me frequently: daily, sometimes multiple times daily, spinning beach balls, unresponsive when the Mac's lid is opened, failing when the screen saver kicks in; you name it, sometimes it could just be my typing something quickly into the Firebox toolbar.

Fortunately turning it off and restarting has, up to now, always worked, but many of the apps don't like it and many apps complain, fail and need reinstalling and I'm getting to the end of my patience.

I'm pondering on just reinstalling Snow Leopard (or waiting for Lion or whatever's next) and seeing if that solves it, but I've no real confidence in that as a solution.

A little background: I'm a professional Windows developer and a Mac user for a number of years, so I'm comfortable with the idea of logging, tracing, debugging and so on, but I'm a little lacking in the deep knowledge of where to look for clues on the Mac.

So I'm looking to the hivemind: if I'm not to just backup everything up and do a clean install, what should I try before that? Or should I just try that? Why should I believe that would work?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  I have a ST9500420AS, is it the same drive?  Mine is loud but I don't have any issues with it.

Does anything show up in the console during/after this occurs?  /Applications/Utilities/Console.app

Also, if you can make the problem re-produceable, you could try fseventer[http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart), or even a simple command into the terminal (`lsof > ~/Desktop/open_files.txt`) to figure out what might be going on.

It almost sounds like it might, might be a hardware problem rather than software, but we may as well rule out the latter first.

Comment: I have the ST95005620AS so it's similar - it has been louder, but a firmware revision (SD24 I think) assisted with that. Console.app ... this might be something, I can't even run that. It bounces in the dock and I then I get a error report and an offer to reopen (repeat to fade)

Comment: @Unsliced - interesting.  Boot from the OS X CD that came with your computer, or a retail copy.  Go through the first screen until you get a menu bar.  Access Utilities -> Disk utility.  You will want to check the disk out and make sure it's okay, as well as verify and repair disk permissions.  Once you've done that come back and let us know if anything's changed.  By chance, did you migrate from an old system/installation, and use Migration Assistant?

Comment: @Harv - very good suggestion at first glance. There were lots of permissions and repair disk had a little work. Mind you, Console.app still doesn't work. The  machine has been on overnight without crashing, so that's some progress at least!

Comment: @Unsliced - Fantastic!  I would take a really good look at why console.app doesn't work (and what else might not be working).  Weird issues like that, while they might not seem terribly significant ("So, I can't see the logs.  So what?") may point to a bigger problem.  Rooting  it out is important, if you want a healthy Mac.  What about my question about migration?

Comment: @Harv when the HDD died, I did a restore (from Carbonite) so while it was a form of migration, it wasn't using Migration Assistant.

Comment: @Unsliced - the best suggestion I have for you is, separate out your data from applications.  Do a clean erase/install, and start fresh with a new system, new fully updated system, and new preferences everywhere.  Make sure you bring over stuff like your old Keychain, Mail, Mail Downloads, and all of the folders that are important, such as Desktop, Documents, etc.  Install apps from disk/internet/whatever.  Clean, fresh slate.